# Python UnboundLocalError on my function return. Something to do with try except?

Tags: python

```
def analyzeList(lst):
    try:
        #minimum
        min = 0
        currentmin = float(lst[0])
        for i in range(0, len(lst)-1):
            if currentmin > float(lst[i+1]):
                currentmin = float(lst[i+1])
                min = currentmin
        print(min)
        #maximum
        max = 0
        currentmax = float(lst[0])
        for i in range(0, len(lst)-1):
            if currentmax < float(lst[i+1]):
                currentmax = float(lst[i+1])
                max = currentmax
        print(max)
        #sum
        sum = 0
        for i in lst:
            sum += i
        
        average = (sum/len(lst))
    
    except ValueError:
        pass
    
    return min, max, sum, average
```

This is my code. I'm trying to get min, max, sum, and average of list that has random number and letters.
Been trying for hours, not sure how to get the pass UnboundLocalError min referenced before assignment.

I tried putting the return inside the try except but that did returned nothing which is as expected but it didn't give me any error code. Seems like the return is thinking that there is no min, max variable?

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'max' referenced before assignment
  File "C:\Users\david\Desktop\Practice Python Files\questions.py", line 60, in analyzeList
    return min, max, sum, average

  File "C:\Users\david\Desktop\Practice Python Files\questions.py", line 70, in main
    data = analyzeList(numbers)

  File "C:\Users\david\Desktop\Practice Python Files\questions.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: _`UnboundLocalError min referenced before assignment`_ The variable `min` is defined at the very top of the `try` block, so I don't see how that specific error could ever happen.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Also, are you aware that there are already functions named `min()` and `max()` to find the smallest and largest items in a list?

Comment: For starters, don’t silently swallow errors. At least log the errors in the `except` block to have a clue what isn’t working and why. Better yet, don’t have such sweeping try blocks without any sensible error handling at all.

Comment: `except ValueError: pass` is a **terrible** way to handle errors.  If you get an error, wouldn't you want to **know** something about it?  But this just ignores the error completely.

Comment: @JohnGordon Its an assignment thing that we have to make our own functions. And yeah my error handling is bad. I know that the error is from string being present in the list while I'm trying to calculate integers.

Comment: We can't help unless you post the full error traceback message.

Comment: Ah sorry. I added the error message.

Comment: Suppressing all errors and then finding debugging difficult is roughly equivalent to removing the brakes from your car and then being surprised when you crash into something. And strangers on the Internet can't help you fix either problem.

Comment: We know the problem is an exception before you hit `max = 0` otherwise `max` would be assigned. Likely one of those `float()` creations failed. So. What do you want the return to look like if you get a value error? You'd return that inside the exception handler.

Comment: Okay, reading a little closer. You want to get data on a _list that has random number and letters._ Does that mean you want to filter out anything that can't be a float and get the stats on what remains?

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would help a lot if you show us an example of input and desired output.

Comment: You've already told us that your function is going to have ValueError. It's got strings inside of id, and calling float() on a string will give you a Value Error.  So min, max, avg, len never get set because the first value is one of the broken values.  Hence the error at the bottom.

Comment: @tdelaney Ohhh I see. I tried putting a try except block for every calculation and it worked. The program encountered an error during the min calculation and then skip to the line after the except block. I incorrectly assumed that it would go back to the to top.

Comment: Pro tip: `try..except` only lines where you *expect* errors to occur and catch only those specific errors you expect and then do something that ensures your program can continue regardless. Don’t `try..except` everywhere or too broad or without an actual recovery plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens when the code hits the first thing in `lst` that can't be converted to a `float`. A `ValueError` is raised while calculating `min` and your code never gets to assigning an initial value to `max`. Execution drops out of the exception handler and you try to return a `max` that never had any value bound to it.

I'm going out on a limb here, but it seems like you want to get stats on the subset of the list that can be converted to a float. That means you need your exception handling inside of the loop. It's easiest to get the float conversion done early and deal with that list for sums etc.

Python has functions for `min`, `max` and `sum`, so no need to do this manually .... but I did anyway.

```
def analyzeList(lst):
    floaters = []
    for value in lst:
        try:
            floaters.append(float(value))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    if not floaters:
        return ??? no floats, what should this be?
        
    min = max = sum = floaters[0]
    for value in floaters[1:]:
        if min > value:
            min = value
        if max < value:
            max = value
        sum += value
    average = sum/len(floaters)
    return min, max, sum, average
```

You could slim this down with

```
def analyzeList(lst):
    floaters = []
    for value in lst:
        try:
            floaters.append(float(value))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    if not floaters:
        return ??? no floats, what should this be?
  
    return min(floaters), max(floaters), mysum:=sum(floaters), mysum/len(floaters)
```